# Align multiple plots with varying spacings and add arrows between them

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I have 6 plots which I want to align neatly in a two-step manner (see picture). Preferably, I'd like to add nice arrows.

Any ideas?

---

UPD. As my question started to gather negative feedback, I want to clarify that I've checked all the (partially) related questions at SO and found no indication on how to position ggplots freely on a "canvas". Moreover, I cannot think of a single way to draw arrows *between* the plots. I'm not asking for a ready made solution. Please, just indicate the way.

[image]

Comment: Use gridExtra's `grid.arrange`/`arrangeGrob` to arrange the plots and then draw the arrows using grid functions.

Comment: Have a look at the code for the `cowplot` package. It arranges plots and then annotates them with labels. It uses `grid.arrange` like Roland suggests. It would probably be a good starting point.

Comment: TBH if this was a one-off task I'd do it with Inkscape.

Comment: @Mike The idea to look through the `cowplot`'s source code looks promising. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Roland I know, it's much easier to do it in a graphical prog. Still, I want to be able to manipulate and arrange ggplots within R. There are lots of benefits. For instance, in this way you may easily insert the output into rmd file.

Answer (score 15):

Here's an attempt at the layout you want. It requires some formatting by hand, but you can probably automate much of that by taking advantage of the coordinate system built into the plot layout. Also, you may find that `grid.curve` is better than `grid.bezier` (which I used) for getting the arrow curves shaped exactly the way you want.

I know just enough about `grid` to be dangerous, so I'd be interested in any suggestions for improvements. Anyway, here goes...

Load the packages we'll need, create a couple of utility `grid` objects, and create a plot to lay out:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# Empty grob for spacing
#b = rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="white", col="white"))  
b = nullGrob() # per @baptiste's comment, use nullGrob() instead of rectGrob()

# grid.bezier with a few hard-coded settings
mygb = function(x,y) {
  grid.bezier(x=x, y=y, gp=gpar(fill="black"), 
              arrow=arrow(type="closed", length=unit(2,"mm")))
}

# Create a plot to arrange
p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
```

Create the main plot arrangement. Use the empty grob `b` that we created above for spacing the plots:

```
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p, b, p, p, heights=c(0.3,0.1,0.3,0.3)),
             b,
             arrangeGrob(b, p, p, b, p, heights=c(0.07,0.3, 0.3, 0.03, 0.3)),
             ncol=3, widths=c(0.45,0.1,0.45))
```

Add the arrows:

```
# Switch to viewport for first set of arrows
vp = viewport(x = 0.5, y=.75, width=0.09, height=0.4)
pushViewport(vp)

#grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill="black", alpha=0.1)) # Use this to see where your viewport is located on the full graph layout

# Add top set of arrows
mygb(x=c(0,0.8,0.8,1), y=c(1,0.8,0.6,0.6))
mygb(x=c(0,0.6,0.6,1), y=c(1,0.4,0,0))

# Up to "main" viewport (the "full" canvas of the main layout)
popViewport()

# New viewport for lower set of arrows
vp = viewport(x = 0.6, y=0.38, width=0.15, height=0.3, just=c("right","top"))
pushViewport(vp)

#grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill="black", alpha=0.1))  # Use this to see where your viewport is located on the full graph layout

# Add bottom set of arrows
mygb(x=c(1,0.8,0.8,0), y=c(1,0.9,0.9,0.9))
mygb(x=c(1,0.7,0.4,0), y=c(1,0.8,0.4,0.4))
```

And here's the resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: Hi @baptiste. I was hoping you would show up and tell me how to do this right. Thanks. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks for the inspiring script.

Comment: @eipi10 not really, personally I use Illustrator for such annotations because i) arrow heads in R/grid don't look so nice; ii) it takes more time to fiddle with hard-coded coordinates than draw it by hand; iii) reproducibility is not a real issue for one-off annotations. Of course there are cases where a fully-scripted solution is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Probably using `ggplot` with `annotation_custom` here is a more convenient approach. First, we generate sample plots.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)
require(bezier)

# generate sample plots
set.seed(17)
invisible(
  sapply(paste0("gg", 1:6), function(ggname) {
    assign(ggname, ggplotGrob(
      ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))) +
        geom_path(aes(x,y), size = 1, 
                  color = colors()[sample(1:length(colors()), 1)]) +
        theme_bw()), 
           envir = as.environment(1)) })
)
```

After that we can plot them inside a bigger `ggplot`.

```
# necessary plot
ggplot(data.frame(a=1)) + xlim(1, 20) + ylim(1, 32) +
  annotation_custom(gg1, xmin = 1, xmax = 9, ymin = 23, ymax = 31) +
  annotation_custom(gg2, xmin = 11, xmax = 19, ymin = 21, ymax = 29) +
  annotation_custom(gg3, xmin = 11, xmax = 19, ymin = 12, ymax = 20) +
  annotation_custom(gg4, xmin = 1, xmax = 9, ymin = 10, ymax = 18) +
  annotation_custom(gg5, xmin = 1, xmax = 9, ymin = 1, ymax = 9) +
  annotation_custom(gg6, xmin = 11, xmax = 19, ymin = 1, ymax = 9) +
  geom_path(data = as.data.frame(bezier(t = 0:100/100, p = list(x = c(9, 10, 10, 11), y = c(27, 27, 25, 25)))),
            aes(x = V1, y = V2), size = 1, arrow = arrow(length = unit(.01, "npc"), type = "closed")) +
  geom_path(data = as.data.frame(bezier(t = 0:100/100, p = list(x = c(9, 10, 10, 11), y = c(27, 27, 18, 18)))),
            aes(x = V1, y = V2), size = 1, arrow = arrow(length = unit(.01, "npc"), type = "closed")) +
  geom_path(data = as.data.frame(bezier(t = 0:100/100, p = list(x = c(15, 15, 12, 9), y = c(12, 11, 11, 11)))),
            aes(x = V1, y = V2), size = 1, arrow = arrow(length = unit(.01, "npc"), type = "closed")) +
  geom_path(data = as.data.frame(bezier(t = 0:100/100, p = list(x = c(15, 15, 12, 9), y = c(12, 11, 11, 9)))),
            aes(x = V1, y = V2), size = 1, arrow = arrow(length = unit(.01, "npc"), type = "closed")) +
  geom_path(data = as.data.frame(bezier(t = 0:100/100, p = list(x = c(15, 15, 12, 12), y = c(12, 10.5, 10.5, 9)))),
            aes(x = V1, y = V2), size = 1, arrow = arrow(length = unit(.01, "npc"), type = "closed")) +
  theme(rect = element_blank(),
        line = element_blank(),
        text = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm"))
```

Here we use `bezier` function from `bezier` package to generate coordinates for `geom_path`. Maybe one should look for some additional information about bezier curves and their control points to make connections between plots look prettier. Now the resulting plot is following.
[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: You posted your answer while I was typing and formatting mine - almost the same))

Comment: I really like the way you generated the sample plots and created the arrows. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot for your tips and especially @eipi10 for an actual implementation of them - the answer is great.
I found a native `ggplot` solution which I want to share.

**UPD** While I was typing this answer, @inscaven posted his answer with basically the same idea. The `bezier` package gives more freedom to create neat curved arrows.

---

#### `ggplot2::annotation_custom`

The simple solution is to use `ggplot`'s `annotation_custom` to position the 6 plots over the "canvas" ggplot.

#### The script

**Step 1**. Load the required packages and create the list of 6 square ggplots. My initial need was to arrange 6 maps, thus, I trigger `theme` parameter accordingly.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)
    
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,wt))+
        geom_point()+
        theme_map()+
        theme(aspect.ratio=1,
              panel.border=element_rect(color = 'black',size=.5,fill = NA))+
        scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
        scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
        labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)

plots <- list(p,p,p,p,p,p)
```

**Step 2**. I create a data frame for the canvas plot. I'm sure, there is a better way to this. The idea is to get a 30x20 canvas like an A4 sheet.

```
df <- data.frame(x=factor(sample(1:21,1000,replace = T)),
                 y=factor(sample(1:31,1000,replace = T)))
```

**Step 3**. Draw the canvas and position the square plot over it.

```
canvas <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
        
        annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(plots[[1]]),
                          xmin = 1,xmax = 9,ymin = 23,ymax = 31)+
        
        annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(plots[[2]]),
                          xmin = 13,xmax = 21,ymin = 21,ymax = 29)+
        annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(plots[[3]]),
                          xmin = 13,xmax = 21,ymin = 12,ymax = 20)+
        
        annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(plots[[4]]),
                          xmin = 1,xmax = 9,ymin = 10,ymax = 18)+
        annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(plots[[5]]),
                          xmin = 1,xmax = 9,ymin = 1,ymax = 9)+
        annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(plots[[6]]),
                          xmin = 13,xmax = 21,ymin = 1,ymax = 9)+
        
        coord_fixed()+
        scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
        scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
        theme_bw()

        theme_map()+
        theme(panel.border=element_rect(color = 'black',size=.5,fill = NA))+
        labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

**Step 4**. Now we need to add the arrows. First, a data frame with arrows' coordinates is required.

```
df.arrows <- data.frame(id=1:5,
                        x=c(9,9,13,13,13),
                        y=c(23,23,12,12,12),
                        xend=c(13,13,9,9,13),
                        yend=c(22,19,11,8,8))
```

**Step 5**. Finally, plot the arrows.

```
gg <- canvas + geom_curve(data = df.arrows %>% filter(id==1),
                    aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend),
                    curvature = 0.1, 
                    arrow = arrow(type="closed",length = unit(0.25,"cm"))) +
        geom_curve(data = df.arrows %>% filter(id==2),
                   aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend),
                   curvature = -0.1, 
                   arrow = arrow(type="closed",length = unit(0.25,"cm"))) +
        geom_curve(data = df.arrows %>% filter(id==3),
                   aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend),
                   curvature = -0.15, 
                   arrow = arrow(type="closed",length = unit(0.25,"cm"))) +
        geom_curve(data = df.arrows %>% filter(id==4),
                   aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend),
                   curvature = 0, 
                   arrow = arrow(type="closed",length = unit(0.25,"cm"))) +
        geom_curve(data = df.arrows %>% filter(id==5),
                   aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend),
                   curvature = 0.3, 
                   arrow = arrow(type="closed",length = unit(0.25,"cm")))
```

---

#### The result

```
ggsave('test.png',gg,width=8,height=12)
```

[image]